# Document Map in MS Word 2007 going bonkers

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I’m working on a large project report in Microsoft Word 2007 and have been using the document map to generate the index. I have been carefully selecting the headers that need to be added to the document map,
but I saved the document and opened it up today to work on it –
the document map has added whatever it pleases there.

[image]

The following is a temporary fix from [a post that I found](http://web.archive.org/web/20120415065531/http://www.bitwisemag.com/2/Microsoft-Word-Expletive-Deleted)
<sup>(The above image is also copied from that page)</sup>
after extensive searching that works,
but when I save and close the document and open it up again
I face the same dilemma:

> I have noticed that when Word stuffs
>   up the document map after opening the
>   file, I can undo this by using the
>   UNDO button. Word calls it ‘Autoformat’.
>
> I have also fixed a file that has had
>   the document map screwed permanently
>   (i.e., saved with it) by selecting all
>   (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), selecting the PARAGRAPH drop
>   down menu in the HOME TAB and in the
>   OUTLINE drop down box, selecting ‘Body Text’.
>   This removed all the problems
>   and did not seem to affect my outline
>   level paragraph headings.

This is also another temporary fix, but I have to be on my toes not to let Word auto format at the start of the document. I also can’t afford to entirely turn off auto format as I need it.

> I’ve solved this problem for me.
>
> When you open the file, a progress bar
>   at the bottom first says Opening (ESC to Cancel)
>   and then it says Word is
>   formatting the document (ESC to Cancel).
>   If I cancel the second
>   process, TOC fine. No cancelling, TOC screwed.
>
> Now, can anyone work out how to switch off the autoformatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problematic section in your Word file that’s causing this.

The part of your document with the most errors in the Document Map, is the one. Extract this to another file. Then copy & paste the remaining contents to a new document and it should be clean. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have Table of Contents or Table of Figures and you update the entire table, the Document Map MUST BE OPEN when you update to maintain the same document map.  If the Document Map button is not clicked and you cannot see the Document map, then when you update a table it will create a new document map and screw it up.

The same thing happens if the Word Application is closed while the Document Map is open.  When Word launches the next time, it thinks it is supposed to create a Document Map for any file opened and screws it up.  Instead, close the document map BEFORE CLOSING Word.  Then when Word opens next time, it doesn't try to create the Document Map.  When you click the Document Map box it will use the existing Document Map you expect.

Also do not save a document with a bad document map or it is the new document map.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with the method
found <del>[here](http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/word-docmanagement/102550/Suddenly-captions-and-other-text-in-document-map-and)</del> or [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.word.docmanagement/AXoznrJ8p_s).

I couldn't find any other working workaround, and I didn't wanted to password protect just to stop auto-format, and didn't wanted to copy all the parts of the document into a new one, etc.

The trick is to create and apply an Outline Level 1 style to something which was Body Text before.

In my "corrupted" document with this behavior (always showing corrupted document map after reopening the document, no matter what formatting or other proposed trick), I saved a new style called "Title 2" (Title was the original, and was "body text" outline) and applied to the "Title" text "Table of Contents". After that I re-applied the style to every "corrupted" parts pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. Now the Document Map works OK.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered many errors like this while tracking changes. The document map attempts to parse the changes instead of ignoring them and can result in errors. If you are tracking changes, try accepting all, or turning off tracking and deleting any changes to headers or heading numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Word 2007, open the document, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (to select the entire document), right-click and choose “Paragraph”.  In the “Paragraph” dialog box, “Indents and Spacing” tab, click the “Outline Level” down arrow, choose “Body Text”, and click “OK”.  (This will not change your heading levels.)

"Save As" the document to a Rich Text File (`.rtf`) then save it back as an MS Word `.docx`.  This has fixed my problem.  Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The document map for my thesis no longer showed some of my headings (despite all using the standard heading style).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in a new doc restored the document map to its correct form.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. Here is my solution (which might be similar in principle to others posted here):
Apply the style “Heading 1” to the very first line of your document. After this, Word will no longer change your outline settings. At least it doesn't in my files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by selecting the faulty text
and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (clear paragraph formatting).

Answer (score -1):

Someone somewhere says that turning off all autoformatting doesn’t work.

Here is a solution involving password protection:

http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/document-map-word-2007-resets-body-text-document-map-answer

but the options he mentions do not appear in my Word for Mac 2011.

Someone else:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/innovateonoffice/thread/92fad1aa-17d0-46b2-b7b3-ec36269f5296

says that the problem only happens when the document is opened with the DM pane open, so you assign the close keystroke (cmd-W) to a script that closes the document map every time you close a document. But when I opened a document with the DM having been shut before, it still happens.

The solution I found (and I think you have to do it for each document that has this problem) is to set any style in the document, ideally one that you don’t use, to Outline Level 1 (level 9 did not work for me). Then create a first line to the document and apply that style to that line (making it the last line did not work for me). I add a second line reminding me not to remove or alter the first line.

This solution is based on the one recommended on this page:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.word.docmanagement/AXoznrJ8p_s

namely:

*What I learned from countless websites on this subject is that when Word  does not find any styles with an attached outline level (except the heading  styles) it start to guess by itself. And it guesses wrong. So I created a single style that has an outline level attached. I chose the  style used for the table of contents. When reopening the document now, no  extra entries are visible, so word has stopped guessing.*

Here is someone using and describing that solution- in a way I don’t understand:

*The trick is to create and apply an Outline Level 1 style to something which was Body Text before. In my "corrupted" document with this behavior (always showing corrupted document map after reopening the document, no matter what formatting or other proposed trick), I saved a new style called "Title 2" (Title was the original, and was "body text" outline) and applied to the "Title" text "Table of Contents". After that I re-applied the style to every "corrupted" parts pressing Control-Q. Now the Document Map works OK.*

Thanks to everyone for sharing your struggles!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution I found was right clicking on an item in the document map and then selecting
"Show Heading 1" and and leave it like that..